# Permission denied in MYSQL with XAMPP when adding a new database

Tags: mysql, wordpress

clone a GitLab project that is developed in Wordpress but when restoring its database it gives me the following error

> Usuario@SYSTEMMASTER MINGW64 /c/xampp/htdocs (master)
> $ sh restore.sh
> restore.sh: line 1: /c/xampp/mysql/bin/mysql: Permission denied

```
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100   139  100    42  100    97     82    190 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--   273
```

```
{"message": "400: Bad Request", "code": 0}
```